# No Static Files Extensions are referable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` referenced in my `project.json`, but the `UseDefaultFiles()` and `UseStaticFiles()` extensions are still not recognised.

The dependencies section of `project.json` is:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
    "type": "platform"
  },
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

I can see the reference in the references section of the solution explorer.  I can see in the [Git repo](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/StaticFileExtensions.cs) that it lives in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder` namespace, as does `UseDefaultFiles()` but I just get a compile error:

```
IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseDefaultFiles' and no extension method 'UseDefaultFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I can, however, access the middleware directly without the extension methods:

```
app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>();
app.UseMiddleware<DefaultFilesMiddleware>();
```

is fine.

What's going on?

Comment: did you install RC2 on your system??

Comment: `dotnet --version` gives `1.0.0-preview1-002702`.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles is an RC1 package

Comment: @DanielGrim Aye, there is no RC2 package... are they not compatible?

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",  Most Microsoft.AspNet.* packages got renamed to Microsoft.AspNetCore.*

Comment: Don't mix RC1 and RC2 packages. That's a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

Like Daniel Grim says:

Change the dependency to:

```
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/1.0.0-rc2-final