# app.UseMiddleware<T>() causing 500

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net5

If I call the middleware directly in my `startup.cs`, e.g.:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<DefaultFilesMiddleware>();
}
```

Looking at the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles), this is exactly the code that the extension methods are calling.  However, I'm getting a 500 error and a stack trace:

```
 :(
Oops.
500 Internal Server Error
System.InvalidOperationException
The 'Invoke' method's first argument must be of type 'HttpContext'.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Show raw exception details

System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Invoke' method's first argument must be of type 'HttpContext'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

This *might* be related to my [No Static Files Extensions are referable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330369/no-static-files-extensions-are-referable) question.

Either way, I currently can't get a simple `index.html` page to load successfully.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Core are you using. Looks like RC1?

Comment: @WillRay The error web page has a footer with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 1.0.0-rc2-20901`, so I think I'm RC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using the RC1 version of the StaticFiles library inside of your project, instead of RC2.

In `project.json`, change this:

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

To this:

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
}
```

The namespace also changed, but once that's corrected you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you!  I was beginning to give up hope!

Answer (score 1):

Since now the asp.net core 1.0 has been released. 
The correct NuGet package is: (notice: .AspNetCore.)

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

and you can use (again)

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just call:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseDefaultFiles();
```

instead of the UseMiddleware methods.