# Asp.net Core web api middleware Error `The 'Invoke' method's first argument must be of type 'HttpContext'`

Tags: c#, middleware, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created following middleware in ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.

**SignalrQsHeaderMiddleware.cs**

```
public class SignalrQsHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SignalrQsHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        /*
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/restaurantHub"))
        {
            var qsHeader = context.Request.Query["access_token"].ToString();
            if (!qsHeader.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization",qsHeader);
            }
        }*/
        await _next.Invoke(context);

    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` added following line.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //Other services.
    app.UseMiddleware<SignalrQsHeaderMiddleware>();//<-- added here
}
```

And when i run project following error occur.

> The 'Invoke' method's first argument must be of type 'HttpContext'. at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(RequestDelegate
>   next)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

[image: Here You can see the error image]

Note: I have try this solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331954/4154016)

But still i am facing the same issue.

Any suggestion what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Accordingly to your screenshot, you have RTM libraries. Try to update all the packages to the latest stable ones.

Comment: Do you reference the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http ? Your code looks great ...

Comment: @Adrien and @Ilya Chumakov thanks . I Updated all packages as well as set reference `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`. Now it's working fine.  :)

Comment: have you tried just `await _next(context)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware is the last one, so there is no "next" item.
Looks like the bug is that we can see wrong error message.
But you must check, if _next != null anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, the error message says that the Invoke methods first param should be of type `HttpContext` . See below code for example. The Invoke method's first param is `IApplicationBuilder`. This creates problem.

```
 public Task Invoke( IApplicationBuilder app, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(error =>
            {
                error.Run(async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("from Exception Handler middleware");
                });
            });
            return  _next(httpContext);
        }
```

Changed this to below. My issue got fixed. It should always be `HttpContext` type as first parameter for Invoke.

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(error =>
            {
                error.Run(async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("from Exception Handler middleware");
                });
            });
            return  _next(httpContext);
        }
```

Please check in your custom middleware if your parameter order is placed as above. I can't see anything on the current middleware of the code you shared. I would suggest you to check in other middlewares as well for the order.